# Exposing DataGrid's cell template as a custom user control property in Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I'm building custom user control in Silverlight 4. The idea behind the control is to move data grid with pager from user page to a control. Currently data grid looks like:

```
                <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="GridCustomers" Height="300" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerModelsPagedCollectionView}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionChanged="GridCustomers_SelectionChanged">
                    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Numer bilingowy" Binding="{Binding BillingNumber}" />
                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Nazwa klienta" Binding="{Binding CustomerName}"/>
                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Skrócona nazwa" Binding="{Binding ShortCustomerName}"/>
                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Kod pocztowy" Binding="{Binding PostalCode}" />
                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Miasto" Binding="{Binding City}" />
                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Ulica" Binding="{Binding Street}" />
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Urządzenia">
                            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox x:Name="DeviceComboBox"  SelectionChanged="DeviceComboBox_SelectionChanged">
                                        <ComboBox.Items>
                                            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Switch" Content="Switche"/>
                                            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Firewall" Content="Firewalle"/>
                                            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Host" Content="Hosty" />
                                        </ComboBox.Items>
                                    </ComboBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                </sdk:DataGrid>
```

What I mostly wanted to achieve apart from removing repetitive code of this grid from few pages, is giving this control flexibility to define that template column by a user. In other words I'm trying to expose DataGrid column property so it is possible to add different DataGridTemplateColumns. Since I have low experience with SL I did some research and according to what I've found 'attached properties' is what I need(need confirmation on this). I defined DependencyProperty using [this tutorial.](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Attached-Properties-in-Silverlight.aspx) like this (controls code - CustomerControl) :

```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ColumnTemplate",
        typeof(DataGridTemplateColumn),
        typeof(CustomerControl),
        null);

public static void SetColumnTemplate(DependencyObject obj, DataGridTemplateColumn column)
{
    obj.SetValue(ColumnTemplateProperty, column);
}

public static DataGridTemplateColumn GetColumnTemplate(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (DataGridTemplateColumn)obj.GetValue(ColumnTemplateProperty);
}
```

Control's XAML:

```
        <local:CustomerControl x:Name="temp" >
            <local:CustomerControl.ColumnTemplate>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="DeviceComboBox"  SelectionChanged="DeviceComboBox_SelectionChanged">
                            <ComboBox.Items>
                                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Switch" Content="Switche"/>
                                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Firewall" Content="Firewalle"/>
                                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Host" Content="Hosty" />
                            </ComboBox.Items>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </local:CustomerControl.ColumnTemplate>
        </local:CustomerControl>
```

Since I exposed property of type 'DataGridTemplateColumn' I fought the rest of template declaration won't change, but this does not work :( I'm not sure about this attached properties. Could you give me some tips how to get this to work the way I presented (or should I say 'imagined' how I want it to work). Is it even possible? I'm aware of fact that there are some major flaws here but just for the record, errors Im getting:

*Error  3   The attachable property 'CellTemplate' was not found in type 'DataGridTemplateColumn' 
Error   2   Unexpected PROPERTYELEMENT in parse rule PropertyElement ::= . PROPERTYELEMENT Content? ENDTAG*

Thank you for any sort of pointer ;)